# N-length sequences of pairs following conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have the following 2d-array of fruits:

```
fruits = [["apple", "lemon"],["apple", "cucumber"],["carrot", "lemon"],["carrot", "cucumber"],["peach", "cucumber"],["lemon", "melon"],["grape", "cucumber"],["lime", "lemon"],["lime", "cucumber"],["apricot", "lemon"],["apricot", "cucumber"],["avocado", "cucumber"],["banana", "lemon"],["banana", "cucumber"],["blackberry", "lemon"],["blackberry", "cucumber"],["blackberry", "prune"],["blueberry", "lemon"],["blueberry", "melon"],["blueberry", "cucumber"],["cherry", "lemon"],["cherry", "cucumber"],["papaya", "lemon"],["plum", "lemon"],["plum", "cucumber"],["feijoa", "lemon"],["fig", "lemon"],["fig", "cucumber"],["eggplant", "lemon"],["eggplant", "cucumber"],["raspberry", "lemon"],["raspberry", "cucumber"],["cranberry", "lemon"],["cranberry", "cucumber"],["pomelo", "lemon"],["pomelo", "cucumber"],["orange", "lemon"],["orange", "cucumber"],["olive", "cucumber"],["gooseberry", "lemon"],["guava", "lemon"],["guava", "blueberry"],["guava", "cucumber"],["redcurrant", "lemon"],["redcurrant", "cucumber"],["pomergranate", "lemon"],["pomergranate", "cucumber"],["nectarine", "cucumber"],["mulberry", "lemon"],["mulberry", "cucumber"],["dragonfruit", "lemon"],["dragonfruit", "cucumber"],["pear", "lemon"],["cucumber", "lemon"],["cucumber", "blueberry"],["cucumber", "salmonberry"],["cucumber", "melon"],["prune", "lemon"],["prune", "guava"],["prune", "cucumber"],["kiwi", "cucumber"],["mangosteen", "cucumber"],["jujube", "lemon"],["jujube", "cucumber"],["clementine", "lemon"],["clementine", "blueberry"],["clementine", "cucumber"],["tangerine", "lemon"],["tangerine", "cucumber"],["pea", "lemon"],["pea", "cucumber"],["tomato", "cucumber"],["yuzu", "cucumber"]]
```

The task is to find N-length sequences of pairs following the conditions:

1. First and last pairs should contain `"lemon"`.
2. Pairs between first and last shouldn't contain `"lemon"`.
3. Each consecutive two pairs should contain a common element.
4. Each consecutive N-1 pairs, where N is not 3, shouldn't contain any element common in all of these pairs.

Examples for N = 4:

```
[["apple","lemon"], ["apple","cucumber"], ["clementine","cucumber"], ["clementine","lemon"]]
[["lime","lemon"], ["lime","cucumber"], ["pomelo","cucumber"], ["pomelo","lemon"]]
[["banana","lemon"], ["banana","cucumber"], ["pomergranate","cucumber"], ["pomergranate","lemon"]]
```

I wrote this code for N = 3 and 4,

```
pairs.permutation(n).select do |ar|
  if n == 3
    (ar[0] & ar[2]) == ["lemon"] && !ar[1].include?("lemon") && (!(ar[0] & ar[1]).empty? && !(ar[1] & ar[2]).empty?)
  elsif n == 4
    (ar[0] & ar[3]) == ["lemon"] && !ar[1].include?("lemon") && !ar[2].include?("lemon") && ((ar[0] & ar[1] & ar[2]).empty? && (ar[1] & ar[2] & ar[3]).empty?) && (!(ar[0] & ar[1]).empty? && !(ar[1] & ar[2]).empty? && !(ar[2] & ar[3]).empty?)
  end
end
```

but I feel this is not the best way. Is there any meta-programming trick to make it universal for any N-length?

Comment: Its not about ruby, you can make it universal in any language. So its not the best in any language. I would suggest you to write you own conditional recursive function the creating the permutation, that will be the most efficient way.

Comment: An observation: This is just dominoes. :)

Comment: @user1735921 OP didn't say it was about Ruby, he just said he wanted the best Ruby approach.

Comment: @moveson Astute observation. Though I haven't seen rule #4 in dominoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution that constructs the desired array directly, rather than constructing a much larger array of permutations and then removing elements that don't satisfy all the rules.

**Code**

```
def combos(n, fruits)
  with_lemon, without_lemon = fruits.partition { |a| a.include?("lemon") }
  return [] if n < 2 || with_lemon.size < 2 || without_lemon.size < n - 2
  with_lemon.each_with_object([]) do |pair, arr|
    recurse(n, n-1, with_lemon - [pair], without_lemon, pair, pair, fruits.flatten).
      each { |a| arr << ([pair] + a) }
  end
end

def recurse(n, n_left, with_lemon, without_lemon, last, in_all_from_1st, in_all_from_2nd)
  if n_left == 1
    with = with_lemon.select { |pair| (last & pair).any? }
    with.select! { |pair| (in_all_from_2nd & pair).empty? } unless n <= 3
    with.map { |pair| [pair] }
  else
    without = without_lemon.select { |pair| (last & pair).any? }
    return [] if without.empty?
    without.each_with_object([]) do |pair, arr|
      if n <= 3 || n_left > 2 || (in_all_from_1st & pair).empty?
        recurse(n, n_left-1, with_lemon, without_lemon-[pair],
          pair, in_all_from_1st, in_all_from_2nd & pair).
          each { |a| arr << ([pair] + a) unless a.empty? }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

To make the example more manageable I've selected 8 of the 73 pairs in the example given by the OP.

```
fruits = [["tomato", "cucumber"], ["fig", "lemon"], ["tomato", "lemon"],
          ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["lemon", "cucumber"], 
          ["pomergranate", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "fig"]]
```

First I'll define a helper. This method returns a pair `[f,n]` where `f` is a fruit and `n` is the number of 2-tuples in which `f` appears, `n` being the largests number of appearances for any fruit.

```
def max_nbr_appearances(n, fruits)
  combos(n, fruits).map do |arr|
    arr.map(&:uniq).flatten.group_by(&:itself).
        transform_values { |v| v.size }.max_by(&:last)
  end.max_by(&:last)
end
```

*n = 2*

```
combos(2, fruits)
  #=> [[["fig", "lemon"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["lemon", "fig"]], 
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]]]
```

*n = 3*

```
combos(n, fruits)
  #=> [[["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  ##   [["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  ##   [["fig", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["fig", "lemon"]], 
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["lemon", "fig"]], \
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "lemon"]], 
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["lemon", "fig"]], 
  ##   [["lemon", "fig"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["tomato", "lemon"]]]
```

Rows above beginning `**` have one fruit that appears in all three 2-tuples (always `"fig"`). That is permitted because `n = 3 <= 3`.

*n = 4*

```
combos(n, fruits)
  #=> [[["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["tomato", "cucumber"],
  #     ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["tomato", "cucumber"],
  #     ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "fig"],
  #     ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "fig"],
  #     ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["tomato", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["cucumber", "fig"],
  #     ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["fig", "tomato"],
  #     ["fig", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["fig", "tomato"],
  #     ["lemon", "fig"]],
  #    [["lemon", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"],
  #     ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["tomato", "cucumber"],
  #     ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["tomato", "cucumber"],
  #     ["lemon", "cucumber"]]]
combos(n, fruits).size
  #=> 10
max_nbr_appearances(n, fruits)
  #=> ["fig", 2]
```

The last calculation shows that "fig" appeared twice in (at least) one permutation and no fruit (including "fig") appeared more than twice in a permutation. (Ties for the largest number of appearance are common. I've shown just one.) The last condition was therefore satisfied.

*n = 5*

```
combos(n, fruits)
  #=> [[["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"],
  #     ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "lemon"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"],
  #     ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    ...
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["cucumber", "fig"],
  #     ["pomergranate", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]]]
combos(n,fruits).size
  #=> 36
max_nbr_appearances(n, fruits)
  #=> ["fig", 3]
```

*n = 6*

```
combos(n,fruits)
  #=> [[["fig", "lemon"], ["cucumber", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], 
  #     ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["pomergranate", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    [["fig", "lemon"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["tomato", "cucumber"],
  # ["cucumber", "fig"], ["pomergranate", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]],
  #    ...
  #    [["lemon", "fig"], ["fig", "tomato"], ["cucumber", "fig"],
  # ["pomergranate", "cucumber"], ["tomato", "cucumber"], ["lemon", "cucumber"]]]
combos(n,fruits).size
  #=> 28
max_nbr_appearances(n, fruits)
  #=> ["cucumber", 4]
```

*n = 7*

```
combos(7,fruits)
  #=> []
```

For `fruits` given in the question, for which `fruits.size #=> 73`, the following results obtained.

```
require 'time'

def ops_fruits(n, fruits)
  t = Time.now
  puts "\ncombos(#{n}, fruits).size = %d, elapsed seconds = %d" %
    [combos(n, fruits).size, Time.now - t]
  puts "max_nbr_appearances(#{n}, fruits) = #{max_nbr_appearances(n, fruits)}"
end

ops_fruits(3, fruits)
combos(3, fruits).size = 64, elapsed seconds = 0
max_nbr_appearances(3, fruits) = ["apple", 2]

ops_fruits(4, fruits)
combos(4, fruits).size = 736, elapsed seconds = 0
max_nbr_appearances(4, fruits) = ["apple", 2]

ops_fruits(5, fruits) 
combos(5, fruits).size = 27822, elapsed seconds = 1
max_nbr_appearances(5, fruits) = ["cucumber", 3]

ops_fruits(6, fruits)
combos(6, fruits).size = 952504, elapsed seconds = 60
max_nbr_appearances(6, fruits) = ["cucumber", 4]
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's really good, and finally i got the idea what is recursion

Comment: this is so fast!

Comment: sometimes it returns `[["pea", "lemon"], ["pea", "cucumber"], ["yuzu", "cucumber"], ["cucumber", "lemon"]]`, which has `cucumber` common in 3 pairs, so condition 4 is not met

Comment: llya, I did an edit to enforce the last requirement correctly. Please check the results carefully. I'll add some explanation as time permits. I've found the best way to fully understand a complex recursive solution is to add some print statements and to indent and "undent" printed output as the method is called and returns.(One of the rare times I use a global variable--for indentation.)

Comment: Thanks, Cary, the results are as expected. Thank you very much for thorough explanation

Comment: Actually, i found out I haven't included one additional condition (each three consequent pairs shouldn't include common element if N >= 3) in the OP, but your example fully covers original 4 conditions. I will try to resolve it using your guidelines

Comment: Also, it seems that if this new condition is satisfied, the old 4th condition is automatically satisfied

Comment: The new condition simplifies the problem considerably. You can remove the last two arguments of `recurse` and change the argument `last` to `last2`, an array of the last 2 pairs. `last2` is what you need to enforce the new requirement and `last2.last` is used as before to satisfy your requirement #3. You;ll want something like `[*last2, pair].reduce(:&).empty?`to be `true` to satisfy the new requirement. Here  `[*last2, pair].reduce(:&)` returns an array of all fruits that appear in the three consecutive pairs `[*last2, pair]`. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Cary, thank you, I was able to produce some working solution https://pastebin.com/ZR9faH7Y.

Comment: I'm curious: is this an exercise or part of an actual application?

Comment: It's part of an application: triangular arbitrage opportunities seeker on crypto exchanges. Imagine sequence: `[['EUR', 'USD'],['USD','AUD'],['AUD','CHF'],['CHF','CNY'],['CNY','EUR']]`: applications looks at best bids / asks of each pair and decides to open trade if it sees profit potential EUR -> X * EUR

Comment: The reasons I use tuples is because in crypto many pairs are represented both in Asset1/Asset2 and Asset2/Asset1 forms simultaneously, and represent different markets and thus orderbooks with different bids and asks

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

The following will enforce all rules with n not limited (didn't check for n < 3).

The first and second rule is easy. Much of the work for the third and fourth rule is done by [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) which will get the arrays one needs in order to become independent of the n.

```
pairs.permutation(n).select do |ar|
  lemon_bracketed = (ar.first & ar.last).include?('lemon')
  no_squeeze = !ar[1..-2].include?('lemon')
  consecutive_pair = ar.each_cons(2).map { |x| x }.none { |first, last| (first & last).empty? }
  consecutive_n = n == 3 || 
                  ar.each_cons(n-1)
                    .map { |x| x }
                    .all? { |group| group[1..-1].reduce(group[0]) { |combination, additional| combination & additional } }

  lemon_bracketed && no_squeeze && consecutive_pair && consecutive_n
end
```

While this works, it is very slow. But the performance seems to be lost at the `pairs.permutation(n)` part so there is not much that can be done here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do a brute-force solution for an arbitrary `length` parameter:

```
class FruitCombinations

  PAIRS = [["apple", "lemon"],["apple", "cucumber"],["carrot", "lemon"],["carrot", "cucumber"],["peach", "cucumber"],["lemon", "melon"],["grape", "cucumber"],["lime", "lemon"],["lime", "cucumber"],["apricot", "lemon"],["apricot", "cucumber"],["avocado", "cucumber"],["banana", "lemon"],["banana", "cucumber"],["blackberry", "lemon"],["blackberry", "cucumber"],["blackberry", "prune"],["blueberry", "lemon"],["blueberry", "melon"],["blueberry", "cucumber"],["cherry", "lemon"],["cherry", "cucumber"],["papaya", "lemon"],["plum", "lemon"],["plum", "cucumber"],["feijoa", "lemon"],["fig", "lemon"],["fig", "cucumber"],["eggplant", "lemon"],["eggplant", "cucumber"],["raspberry", "lemon"],["raspberry", "cucumber"],["cranberry", "lemon"],["cranberry", "cucumber"],["pomelo", "lemon"],["pomelo", "cucumber"],["orange", "lemon"],["orange", "cucumber"],["olive", "cucumber"],["gooseberry", "lemon"],["guava", "lemon"],["guava", "blueberry"],["guava", "cucumber"],["redcurrant", "lemon"],["redcurrant", "cucumber"],["pomergranate", "lemon"],["pomergranate", "cucumber"],["nectarine", "cucumber"],["mulberry", "lemon"],["mulberry", "cucumber"],["dragonfruit", "lemon"],["dragonfruit", "cucumber"],["pear", "lemon"],["cucumber", "lemon"],["cucumber", "blueberry"],["cucumber", "salmonberry"],["cucumber", "melon"],["prune", "lemon"],["prune", "guava"],["prune", "cucumber"],["kiwi", "cucumber"],["mangosteen", "cucumber"],["jujube", "lemon"],["jujube", "cucumber"],["clementine", "lemon"],["clementine", "blueberry"],["clementine", "cucumber"],["tangerine", "lemon"],["tangerine", "cucumber"],["pea", "lemon"],["pea", "cucumber"],["tomato", "cucumber"],["yuzu", "cucumber"]]

  def self.list_valid(length)
    PAIRS.permutation(length).select do |pair_permutation|
      first = pair_permutation[0]
      middle = pair_permutation[1..-2]
      last = pair_permutation[-1]
      first & last == ['lemon'] &&
          middle.none? { |pair| pair.include?('lemon') } &&
          !(first & middle[0]).empty? &&
          !(middle[-1] & last).empty? &&
          middle.each_cons(2).none? { |pair_of_pairs| (pair_of_pairs[0] & pair_of_pairs[-1]).empty? }
    end
  end
end
```

Note this is very slow for length == 4 and will be even slower for longer lengths. As someone pointed out, a recursive solution will be much more efficient.

Comment: thank you so much, i was puzzled which answer to accept, and decided to accept ulferts's answer since it accounts for condition 4

Answer (score 1):

In the abstract:

The data structure is a graph - each fruit is a vertex and the pairs in your array are the edges between them.

To solve it perform a depth-first-search.

> First and last pairs should contain "lemon".
>   Pairs between first and last shouldn't contain "lemon".

- The DFS should be rooted at the `"lemon"` node (level 0).
- The DFS should not descend more than `N` levels.
- The DFS should visit the `"lemon"` node again unless it is at level `N`.

> Each consecutive two pairs should contain a common element.

- This is implicit of the graph data structure.

> Each consecutive N-1 pairs, where N is not 3, shouldn't contain any element common in all of these pairs.

- Maintain a flag on each vertex (fruit) of whether the vertex has been visited - if it has not then the DFS can traverse an edge to it and mark it as visited (and once you backtrack to find other paths then mark it as unvisited so those paths can visit it).